# How should stash-capacity be bounded in Akka?

Tags: akka

I am trying to verify when an `StashOverflowException` is thrown in an `Actor with Stash`. To that end, I have set the `stash-capacity` to some upper bound as follows:

```
akka.actor.deployment.default-mailbox.stash-capacity = 10
```

and have implemented a simple Actor that stashes all messages that it receives. The Actor then signals the sender, if stashing is succeeded or not:

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorSystem, Props, Stash, StashOverflowException }

object StashExample {
  val SUCCESS        = "success"
  val FAILURE        = "failure"
  val STASH_CAPACITY = 10
}

final class StashExample extends Actor with Stash {

  import StashExample._

  var count = 0

  override def receive = {
    case _: String =>
      count += 1
      System.out.println(s"Received ${count} messages.")
      try {
        stash()
        sender ! SUCCESS
      } catch {
        case _: StashOverflowException => sender ! FAILURE
      }
  }
}
```

The problem is that no matter how many messages are sent to this actor, no `StashOverflowException` is thrown.

Here's a simple test that tries to verify this:

```
import akka.testkit.{ ImplicitSender, TestKit }
import org.scalatest.{ BeforeAndAfterAll, Matchers, WordSpecLike }

final class Test
    extends TestKit(ActorSystem("Test"))
    with ImplicitSender
    with WordSpecLike
    with Matchers
    with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  import StashExample._

  "stash operation" should {
    "throw overflow exception when the stash is full" in {
      val actorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new StashExample()))

      // ensure stash-capacity is configured as expected.
      system.settings.config
        .getInt("akka.actor.deployment.default-mailbox.stash-capacity") shouldBe STASH_CAPACITY

      // make the stash full.
      (0 until STASH_CAPACITY).foreach(_ => {
        actorRef ! "ping"
        expectMsg(SUCCESS)
      })

      actorRef ! "ping"
      expectMsg(FAILURE)
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the test failure:

```
Received 1 messages.
Received 2 messages.
Received 3 messages.
Received 4 messages.
Received 5 messages.
Received 6 messages.
Received 7 messages.
Received 8 messages.
Received 9 messages.
Received 10 messages.
Received 11 messages.

assertion failed: expected failure, found success
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: expected failure, found success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `deployment` in the config key:

```
akka.actor.default-mailbox.stash-capacity = 10
```

Comment: Cool, that fixed the problem. Thanks :)